# MVC 3 Partial View not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Instead of rending the partial view on the page, it loads on a new page. Here is my code:

CONTROLLER:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Batch = 0;
        return View();            
    }

    public PartialViewResult ViewMore(int batch)
    {
        ViewBag.Batch = batch;
        var artist = db.Artists.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(10 * batch).Take(10);
        return PartialView("_ViewMoreArtist", artist);
    }
```

VIEW (Index)

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View More...",
    "ViewMore", new { batch = ViewBag.Batch + 1}, new AjaxOptions
    {
         UpdateTargetId = "viewMore",
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
         HttpMethod = "GET"
         //,LoadingElementId = "progress"                     
    })

<div id="viewMore"></div>
```

VIEWS - (_ViewMoreArtist)
   @model IEnumerable

```
@foreach (var artist in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(artist.Name, "Browse", new { id = artist.ArtistId })
    <br />
}
```

VIEWS - (_Layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")"  type="text/javascript">/script>      
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  </head> <body>

<div id="main">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
 </body> </html>
```

NOTES: I already added the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js on the _Layout... What I am trying to do here is using the sample MVCMusicStore project, I added page to view artist with 10 results and an option to view more result...

Comment: Can you post your _Layout view?

Comment: i now modified the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to verify:

- The file `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` exists in the `Scripts` folder
- The file `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` exists in the `Scripts` folder.
- You don't have any javascript errors in the debug console of your browser (FireBug recommended)
- You have unobtrusive javascript ajax enabled in your web.config:

  ```
  <appSettings>
      ...
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  ```

Things to try:

- Use a more recent version of jquery (at least 1.5), I am not sure that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is compatible with jQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: Gotcha! the jquery version was the culprit... :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have _ViewMoreArtist.cshtml page ? In the code above I cant see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog which has a solution

Mostly the javascript files are outdated.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/11/17/mvc-3-ajax-redirecting-instead-of-updating-div.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage